# Removing Ceiling Fan with two switches - with a light fixture. Can I make one switch an outlet?

Tags: switch, receptacle, ceiling-fan

Technically I don’t need any switches since I’m using smart bulbs, but is there a way I can make one of the switches an outlet?  The ceiling fan wires are Ground, Red, White and Black.

I’ll have to open the switch box to take a photo, but no there was no outlet before. There are three switches. 1 that was for the fan, 1 that was for the light and 1 that is for an outlet. The one for the outlet is working fine, and is being left alone. Currently I’ve hooked the light’s white to the house red wire and the lights black to house black and I can get the lights to work with the switch. I’m hoping I can replace the other switch with an outlet.

Comment: Are you wanting to make an existing outlet switched or add a new outlet? Also, can you post photos of the inside of the corresponding switch box please?

Comment: Two switches means either separate switches for light and fan or switches at two locations.  I'm guessing light and fan switches from the wires you have, but you should add a picture or diagram of the switch box(es).  If it's a double gang box, you can likely install a plug and *still* have separate light and fan switches by using a single strap double switch.

Comment: While the NEC does allow the use of a white wire as a hot in some instances, with small conductors a white or grey must be used as a neutral if a neutral is needed. Your description of connecting a white to a hot doesn't seem legal or safe.. l can't think of a configuration where it would not be possible to accomplish as suggested, and the extra switched receptacle feeding from the switch box makes it more likely possible, but opens too many variables that a clear explanation of the changes is difficult without seeing a diagram or pictures of all connections to the switches and the fan/light.